# How do I check if a method returns a true or false?

Tags: java

So I have this code

```
public static boolean isVowel (char c) { 

        if (c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u')
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this code in two seperate methods

```
    if (isVowel == true()) //I know this is wrong but how could I make it work?
        {
            //run command
        }
        else 
        {
            //run command
        }
```

how could I make `if (isVowel())` test if `if isVowel` true?

Comment: `if (isVowel('e'))`. Beginners sometimes do `if (isVowel('e') == true)` like you're trying to formulate, but this is just more verbose (and where does it end? `if (((isVowel('e') == true) == true) == true)`?)

Comment: you can also refactor your isVowel method to immediately return the result like 
_return c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u'_.

Comment: `return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');`  That will return true or false, because the result of that (long compound) boolean expression is true or false (that's how the `if()` statement knows it's true or false, because you have to provide a t/f boolean expression to `if()` in the first place :-)

Comment: You could also say `boolean b = (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');` and then `b` would hold the `true` or `false` result of your expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static boolean isVowel (char c) { 
    // concise code here
    return (c=='a'|| c=='e'|| c=='i'|| c=='o'|| c=='u');
}

// your fix here
if (isVowel(aCharVariable)) {
    // your code here
} else {
    // your code here
}
```

Concise and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the question right but here is what I think meets your requirements:

```
if (isVowel(/* put a char here */) == true) {
     // Do stuff
} else {
    // Do other stuff
}
```

In this case (because `isVowel()` is of type `boolean` you can also do this which is more elegant:

```
if (isVowel(/* put a char here */)) {
    // Do stuff...
```

This is possible because the if statement checks for conditions which is nothing else than a boolean state (`true` or `false`).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, an `if` statement checks whether its operand is `true` or `false`. Operands can only be of type `boolean` (and to a certain extent the boxed `Boolean` variant).

```java
boolean b = true;
if (b) {
  System.out.println("b was true");
}
```

Instead of assigning the static value/the literal `true` to the variable, you can also assign the result of a method call:

```java
boolean b = isVowel('a');
if (b) {
  System.out.println("a is a vowel");
}
```

Now, you do not necessarily need the variable, you can inline it and use the result of the method call directly:

```java
if (isVowel('e')) {
  System.out.println("e is a vowel too");
}
```

Note that some operators, such as `==`, `!=`, `<`, return boolean values as well:

```java
boolean greater = 5 > 3;
boolean equal = null == null;
boolean different = new Object() == new Object();

if (greater) {
  System.out.println("5 is greater than 3");
}

if (equal) {
  System.out.println("null equals null");
}

if (different) {
  System.out.println("Two object instances have different idententity");
}
```

Of course, you do not need variables here and can put the comparison expression directly into the if:

```java
if (5 > 3) {
  System.out.println("5 is greater than 3");
}

if (null == null) {
  System.out.println("null equals null");
}

if (new Object() == new Object()) {
  System.out.println("Two object instances have different idententity");
}
```

or even:

```java
if ((5 < 3) == false) {
  System.out.println("The (logical) statement '5 is less than 3' is false. Therefore, the result of the boolean comparison is true and this code is executed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write it that gets rid of all the ors.

```
private static final Set<Character> VOWELS = ImmutableSet.of('a','e','i','o','u');
public boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return VOWELS.contains(c);
}

if(isVowel('a')) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: With Java 9+ you do not need to rely on Guava anymore and can simply use `Set.of` to create immutable sets. It is already contained in the Java standard library :)

Comment: I, unfortunately, am stuck a 8.